# ffmpeg - How to create a video with a PNG file and keep the same colors

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, inkscape, image-processing

I use a PNG file to create a video.

I create the PNG file with Inkscape.

The SVG file in Inkscape, the PNG file opened in Chrome show the same colors.

Nevertheless the colors of the video (opened in VLC and the app Movies and TV of Windows) are the same **but different than the PNG file**.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/6 -i 1_png_srgb.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuvj420p output.mp4
```

color of the PNG :
[image]

color of the video :
[image]

How to do to get similar colors ?

*For those who, bizarrely, see the the two colours as the same, here's a composite of both (as both now share the same profile the difference should be visible even on the least colour-compliant browsers [Firefox & Chrome])*

[image]

Comment: I don't see any difference in color with the provided example, also when skipping `pix_fmt` altogether. I'm using latest `ffmpeg-full` package on Windows and opening with VLC. What's your system and ffmpeg version?

Comment: What you could try though is use `libx264rgb` codec instead since the input is RGBA, it uses `bgr24` pixel format by default. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Sam - idk ffmpeg at all, but the usual issue going from photo to movie is that the profile is incorrect, sRGB to Rec709 etc, which changes the gamma curve significantly [though this seems more than just that change]. If you have Photoshop or even Gimp, try converting the pngs to your output profile first.

Comment: @Sam no reply from you but I posted as an answer since even if that's not it for you it might help someone else

Answer (score 0):

You can use `libx264rgb` filter instead of `libx264` for better compatibility with RGB pixel formats, which PNGs are using:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/6 -i 1_png_srgb.png -c:v libx264rgb -r 30 output.mp4
```

ffmpeg then uses, by default, `bgr24` as default pixel format and colors are more likely to match.

See also [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libx264_002c-libx264rgb)

> The libx264rgb encoder is the same as libx264, except it accepts
> packed RGB pixel formats as input instead of YUV.